# Windows 10: 64 GB RAM available but only 32 GB Usable

Tags: windows-10, memory

I have an [MSI B450M Bazooka Motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/B450M-BAZOOKA/Specification) and 4 sticks of RAM, 16GB each [GSKILL F4-3000C15D-32GVR](https://www.gskill.com/en/product/f4-3000c15d-32gvr). The third and fourth sticks of RAM were installed after the system was set up.

The [BIOS is version 7A38vH3](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450M-BAZOOKA).

The operating system is Windows 10 Home (64 bit).

Windows sees the full 64 GB, but shows only 32 GB as usable.

[image: Usable Memory Screenshot]

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: That memory is not on the [QVL](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/support/B450M-BAZOOKA#support-mem-12) for 4-module use. When taking your hardware to the limits, always refer to the QVL or you’re on your own.

Comment: which slots did you plug the sticks? Typically the pairs should be interleaved instead of next to each other

Comment: Can you please try... Going to "System Configuration" -> "Boot" tab -> "Advanced Options" -> Tick "Maximum Memory", adjust to "65536" if this is not the initial value that appears. Once you have done this restart your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Daniel B is correct. A different RAM kit shown on the QVL to support 4 DIMMs solved the problem. Windows shows all 64 GB as usable now.

Comment: Ouch. Where you able to change them at the store?